# appendChild Not Working

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-traversal

HTML:

```
<ul id="datalist">
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
function add(content){
   ul=document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
   var li=document.createElement("li");
   li.innerHTML=content;
   ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

When I call `add`, `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'appendChild'` is thrown. Any idea why?

Comment: If no jquery, then why add it as a tag for the question?

Comment: sorry,,,I don't really know where it is tagged with Jquery. the tags are javascript and dom. right?

Comment: When the question was created it was tagged with `jQuery` - Jasper has edited it to replace that with `javascript` instead.

Comment: sorry,,,that must be my mistake....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) does not return one element, it returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList), which is an array-like object. It basically means you can use it as an array.

So you could do for example:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
```

But why don't you simply use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById), if that list has an ID anyways? IDs must be unique in the whole document, so this method will only return one element.

```
var ul = document.getElementById('datalist');
```

---

**Note:** Please be sure to declare `ul` as a local variable to your function (add `var`), unless you mean to use it outside the function.

Comment: when I use getElementById, the console out put 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null'

Comment: @bingije2680 My [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CB9tD/) shows that it works fine :). Please check the link, and if you still have problems, create a fiddle about your scenario.

Answer (score 5):

document.getElementsByTagName doesn't return a Element, but returns an Array of Elements.

You need to loop this array or get some unique Element.

Look this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

```
// check the alignment on a number of cells in a table. 

var table = document.getElementById("forecast-table"); 
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
    var status = cells[i].getAttribute("data-status"); 
    if ( status == "open" ) { 
        // grab the data 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem you have is that `getElementsByTagName()` (note the plural implied by the 's' in the name of the function) returns an *array* of DOM nodes, not a single DOM node, which is what `appendChild()` expects to work on; therefore you need to identify which of the array of nodes you want to work with:

```
function add(content){
   ul=document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]; // the [0] identifies the first element of the returned array
   var li=document.createElement("li");
   li.innerHTML=content;
   ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Remember that if there's only *one* `ul` on the page, you could use `getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]` *or* (and this might be preferable) add an `id` attribute to that `ul` and then select it with `getElementById()`, which will, as expected, return just that one `id`.

References:

- [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).
- [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).